# Remove subdirectory in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I am using apache2.2 and I want to use httpd.conf to pass-through url from one url to another. But I have a problem if the url is not the root domain.

And here is my configuration code in httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/publish

RewriteRule ^/publish /inquery?result=inquery_publish [L,PT]

</IfModule>
```

For example:

if the user type : `localhost/publish`

it should be: `localhost/inquery?result=inquery_publish`

but it look like this: `localhost/home/test/inquery?result=inquery_publish`

So I want to remove the `/home/test/` and it remains only `localhost/`.How could I do with `httpd.conf`?

Any solution and suggestion will be appreciated.

Best regards,

Sokly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?publish inquery?result=inquery_publish [L,QSA,NC,PT]
```

Also take out your `RewriteCond` as it is not needed.

Comment: OK can you add `RewriteBase /` before this rule?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making these changes.